# Improving search results with solr + sunspot

Tags: ruby-on-rails, solr, sunspot

I'm wondering if there was anything I could do help improve a search result I'm seeing with solr.

I have a Product model with a text field "name" with the value "The Glenlivet 18 year".

I have this searchable block in my Product model:

```
searchable do
  text :name
end
```

When I search for "The Glenlivet Single Malt Scotch 18 Yr. 750ML", I get zero results.

```
1.9.3-p0 :001 > Product.search { fulltext "The Glenlivet Single Malt Scotch 18 Yr. 750ML"}.results
=> []
```

It seems like I have to really boil down the search query to get a result, which isn't very useful.

```
1.9.3-p0 :002 > Product.search { fulltext "The Glenlivet 18 Yr. 750ML"}.results
=> []

1.9.3-p0 :006 > Product.search { fulltext "The Glenlivet Single Malt 18"}.results
=> []
```

It really seams like this one should work.

```
1.9.3-p0 :003 > Product.search { fulltext "The Glenlivet 18 Yr."}.results
=> []
```

Then finally

```
1.9.3-p0 :007 > Product.search { fulltext "Glenlivet 18"}.results
Product Load (0.2ms)  SELECT `products`.* FROM `products` WHERE `products`.`id` IN (8)
=> [#<Product id: 8, name: "The Glenlivet 18 year"]
```

It's all the default settings in solr that the sunspot_solr gem creates. Here are my config files:

- [schema.xml](http://pastebin.com/53ryHT6H)
- [synonyms.txt](http://pastebin.com/yLD5Mn06)
- [solrconfig.xml](http://pastebin.com/408T1BZv)

With these kind of results it pretty much defeats the purpose of full text search. Are there any settings I can tweak or anything else I can do so that these results don't seem as strict?

Edit:

Adding the `:minimum_match => 4` and setting the synonyms seems to provide the results I want.

```
Product.search { fulltext "The Glenlivet Single Malt Scotch 18 Yr. 750ML", :minimum_match => 4}.results
```

Comment: Could you post the definition of the fulltext field and its fieldType from your `schema.xml`?

Comment: I added my schema.xml http://pastebin.com/53ryHT6H

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure your fullext field is treated as text and not a string then look at the minimum match setting:

http://wiki.apache.org/solr/DisMaxQParserPlugin#mm_.28Minimum_.27Should.27_Match.29

Also, you might need synonym to equate year and yr.

Comment: Where can I find that setting? I tried adding only the synonym "yr => year", and I still get zero results with "Product.search { fulltext "The Glenlivet 18 yr"}.results". I made sure to restart solr, and reindex whenever I made changes to synonyms.txt.

Comment: mm would be set as part of the dismax query handler in solrconfig.

Comment: you need to configure the synonym filter factor at either index or query time. info on that class is here:  http://wiki.apache.org/solr/AnalyzersTokenizersTokenFilters#solr.SynonymFilterFactory

Comment: Looks like I can set minimum match at search time with :minimum_match => 4

Comment: Do you have an example of this written in your config? There's no documentation anywhere on this.